# Does it make a difference in CPU usage how long you sleep in an infinite loop?

Tags: python, performance, raspberry-pi3, infinite-loop

I'm running some similar python code on my raspberry pi 3, which basically reads values from different sensors and buffers them into a deque to later store them to a file. My CPU load used to be at 100% until I added the sleep function, now it's down to 89% but that's still too high. I cannot see a significant change in CPU usage for different sleep() times, as long as there is a sleep time.

```
while not EventStopAll.isSet():
    time.sleep(self.cpu_relieve_time)
    if self.__new_detection_event(DetectionEvent):
        # do something
    if EventStopMeasuring.isSet() and self.detectionEvent_active:
        # do something else
```

Comment: What is the value of `self.cpu_relieve_time`?

Comment: currently 10 ms

Comment: 89% CPU usage with 10 ms loops is weird/suspicious unless the `do something` part is intensive (or the event management itself is not efficient).

Comment: A Raspberry Pi has 4 CPU cores. What are the other 3 doing?

Comment: I'm reading from quite a lot of different sensors, where each sensor runs in a own thread and also the buffer of each sensor runs in its own thread. The code shown is only the main function which will tell in which buffer to write, when to merge the buffers and when to write the buffers to a file. But in the end of the day it's the same problem: every thread has some sort of endless loop similar to the code shown with a sleep function in it.

Comment: But yes, of course, the longer you sleep, the less frequently will the other code run.

Comment: Maybe try putting a sleep into the loop of each thread. Try running `htop` to see what is going on in each core.